# How to decrypt the authentication buffer obtained from the secure desktop

Tags: c#, winapi, credentials

I'm trying to request the user to enter credentials on the *secure desktop*, but I can't find a way to decrypt the resulting authentication buffer:

*The credentials are obtained with:*

```
CREDUI_INFO cui = new CREDUI_INFO()
{
    cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CREDUI_INFO)),
    pszMessageText = "MyMessage",
    pszCaptionText = "MyCaption",
};

bool save = false;
uint authPackage = 0U;
IntPtr authBuffer;
uint authBufferSize;

uint error = CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials(
                ref cui,
                0U,
                ref authPackage,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                0U,
                out authBuffer,
                out authBufferSize,
                ref save,
                CREDUIWIN_SECURE_PROMPT);
```

*The credentials  are unpacked with:*

```
uint userBufferSize = CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH;
uint domainBufferSize = CRED_MAX_STRING_LENGTH;
uint passwordBufferSize = CREDUI_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH;
StringBuilder userBuffer = new StringBuilder((int)userBufferSize);
StringBuilder domainBuffer = new String((int)domainBufferSize);
IntPtr passwordBuffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)passwordBufferSize);

bool success = CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer(
                CRED_PACK_PROTECTED_CREDENTIALS,
                authBuffer, authBufferSize
                userBuffer, ref userBufferSize,
                domainBuffer, ref domainBufferSize,
                passwordBuffer, ref passwordBufferSize);
```

If I specify `CREDUIWIN_SECURE_PROMPT` in `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` as in the example above, `CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer` fails with `ERROR_NOT_CAPABLE`. If I use `CREDUIWIN_GENERIC` instead of the *secure desktop*, it succeeds.

**How do I obtain the name, domain and password from such encrypted credentials from the secure desktop?** *Or how could I use them generally if that would not be possible?*

Comment: I have similar issue - i got the password as some encrypted blob if specified, and same happens with domain buffer, if i enable secret desktop...

Comment: I'm at a halt here as well. A secure prompt indeed... most can't use it...

Comment: The bounty attracted two [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiarisers.

Answer (score 2):

Credential providers use [`CredProtectW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/nf-wincred-credprotectw) or `CredProtectEx` for encrypting a password. The [`CredUnPackAuthenticationBufferW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/nf-wincred-credunpackauthenticationbufferw) with `CRED_PACK_PROTECTED_CREDENTIALS` attempts to decrypt the credentials (password) in the authentication buffer by using [`CredUnprotectW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/nf-wincred-credunprotectw) or `CredUnprotectEx`. The error - **ERROR_NOT_CAPABLE** is returned exactly by `CredUnprotectW`.

> *The security context used to encrypt the credentials is different from the security context used to decrypt the credentials.*

This is because, when `CREDUIWIN_SECURE_PROMPT` used - for collecting user credentials, the system runs *LogonUI.exe* in context as the system process. And password encrypted in the context of this process. when you run in another security context - user process.

If you don't have any administrator group enabled in the token, you can do nothing with this - you can pass this credentials to system, say, via [`LsaLogonUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-lsalogonuser), but you can not decrypt a password. In case you have "admin", you can impersonate with a system token and then call `CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer(CRED_PACK_PROTECTED_CREDENTIALS,..)` while your thread is impersonating.

Or you can call `CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer(0,..)` **without** `CRED_PACK_PROTECTED_CREDENTIALS` and then separate the unprotected password by calling `CredUnprotectW` while impersonating the system token. Or, if you can not impersonate the system token, how minimum you can get user name. But it can not access the password. If you call `CredIsProtectedW` on the returned password, you mast get `CredTrustedProtection`.

Code for impersonating the system token:

```
inline ULONG BOOL_TO_ERROR(BOOL f)
{
    return f ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
}

NTSTATUS ImpersonateSystemToken(PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi)
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;

    do
    {
        (ULONG_PTR&)pspi += NextEntryOffset;

        HANDLE hProcess, hToken;

        CLIENT_ID ClientId = { pspi->UniqueProcessId };

        if (ClientId.UniqueProcess)
        {
            const SECURITY_QUALITY_OF_SERVICE sqos = {
                sizeof (sqos), SecurityImpersonation, SECURITY_DYNAMIC_TRACKING, FALSE
            };

            const OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa_sqos = { sizeof(oa_sqos), 0, 0, 0, 0, const_cast<SECURITY_QUALITY_OF_SERVICE*>(&sqos) };

            if (0 <= NtOpenProcess(&hProcess, PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION,
                const_cast<POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES>(&oa_sqos), &ClientId))
            {
                status = NtOpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_DUPLICATE|TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);

                NtClose(hProcess);

                if (0 <= status)
                {
                    TOKEN_STATISTICS ts;
                    if (0 <= (status = NtQueryInformationToken(hToken, TokenStatistics, &ts, sizeof(ts), &ts.DynamicCharged)))
                    {
                        status = STATUS_NOT_FOUND;

                        static const LUID SystemLuid = SYSTEM_LUID;

                        if (ts.AuthenticationId.LowPart == SystemLuid.LowPart &&
                            ts.AuthenticationId.HighPart == SystemLuid.HighPart)
                        {
                            status = NtDuplicateToken(hToken, TOKEN_IMPERSONATE|TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES,
                                const_cast<POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES>(&oa_sqos), FALSE, TokenImpersonation, &hProcess);
                        }
                    }

                    NtClose(hToken);

                    if (0 <= status)
                    {
                        const TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp_TCB = { 1, { { { SE_TCB_PRIVILEGE }, SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED } } };

                        if (STATUS_SUCCESS == NtAdjustPrivilegesToken(hProcess, FALSE,
                            const_cast<TOKEN_PRIVILEGES*>(&tp_TCB), sizeof(tp_TCB), 0, 0))
                        {
                            status = NtSetInformationThread(NtCurrentThread(), ThreadImpersonationToken, &hProcess, sizeof(hProcess));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            status = -1;
                        }

                        NtClose(hProcess);

                        if (-1 != status)
                        {
                            return status;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset);

    return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
}

NTSTATUS ImpersonateSystemToken()
{
    BOOLEAN WasEnabled;
    RtlAdjustPrivilege(SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE, TRUE, FALSE, &WasEnabled);

    NTSTATUS status;

    ULONG cb = 0x40000;

    do
    {
        status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;

        if (PBYTE buf = new BYTE[cb += 0x1000])
        {
            if (0 <= (status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &cb)))
            {
                status = ImpersonateSystemToken((PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION)buf);

                if (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
                {
                    status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
                }
            }

            delete [] buf;
        }

    } while(status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    return status;
}
```

And you can use this as:

```
    if (0 <= ImpersonateSystemToken())
    {
        if (CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer(CRED_PACK_PROTECTED_CREDENTIALS, pvOutAuthBuffer, ulOutAuthBufferSize,
            szUserName, &cchUserName, szDomainName, &cchDomainName, szPassword, &cchPassword))
        {
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            GetLastError();
        }

        SetThreadToken(0, 0);
    }
```

Or in this way:

```
    if (CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer(0, pvOutAuthBuffer, ulOutAuthBufferSize,
        szUserName, &cchUserName, szDomainName, &cchDomainName, szPassword, &cchPassword))
    {
        HRESULT hr = DecryptPassword(szPassword, cchPassword);
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        GetLastError();
    }
```

and

```
HRESULT DecryptPassword(PWSTR szPassword, ULONG cchPassword)
{
    CRED_PROTECTION_TYPE ProtectionType;

    HRESULT hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(BOOL_TO_ERROR(CredIsProtectedW(szPassword, &ProtectionType)));

    if (S_OK == hr)
    {
        ULONG cch = 0;
        PWSTR pszCredentials = 0;

        switch (ProtectionType)
        {
        case CredUnprotected:
            pszCredentials = szPassword, cch = cchPassword;
            break;

        case CredTrustedProtection:
        case CredForSystemProtection:
            if (0 > (hr = ImpersonateSystemToken()))
            {
                hr |= FACILITY_NT_BIT;
                break;
            }
            [[fallthrough]];

        case CredUserProtection:
            while (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == (hr = BOOL_TO_ERROR(CredUnprotectW(
                FALSE, szPassword, cchPassword, pszCredentials, &cch))))
            {
                if (pszCredentials)
                {
                    break;
                }

                pszCredentials = (PWSTR)alloca(cch * sizeof(WCHAR));
            }
            if (ProtectionType != CredUserProtection) SetThreadToken(0, 0);
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(hr);
            break;
        default:
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_NT(STATUS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
        }

        if (0 <= hr)
        {
            DbgPrint("pass= \"%.*S\"\n", cch, pszCredentials);
        }
    }

    return hr;
}
```