# Forcing UAC dialog prompt on ShellExecute() C++

Tags: windows, winapi, uac

I'm running `ShellExecute()` with the `"runas"` verb in order to start a process that needs permission to reboot the computer.

*Imagine a scenario where there are two admin accounts - one with shutdown group policy **enabled** and one with it **disabled**.*

When the main process is started elevated by the admin account that does not have permission to execute a reboot, `ShellExecute("runas")` will not display a UAC prompt since the main process is already running elevated. This ends up not giving the user the opportunity to input the credentials of the account that has reboot permissions, and so the reboot is unsuccessful.

---

I guess a very non-elegant way of solving this issue would be to create an entirely new non-elevated process with the sole purpose of running `ShellExecute("runas")` to display the UAC prompt. However, according to [this 2008 blog post on UAC](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide), it's not particularly easy to "start a process non-elevated from the elevated process".

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question but maybe you're looking for ShellExecuteEx with `lpVerb` set to "runas" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfow).

Comment: @SimonMourier That is my current solution at the moment. However, using ShellExecuteEx with "runas" verb does not prompt UAC if the process it is run in is already elevated, which causes the issue I described on the post.

Comment: In a SO question, it's good practise to put everything you do or tried already to save everyone's time.

Comment: My bad, added the information about the current solution using the 'runas' verb

Comment: "*it's not particularly easy to "start a process non-elevated from the elevated process"*" - actually, it is. See [How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process and vice versa?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643) and [How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process, redux](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190425-00/?p=102443)

Comment: You can use CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials for ask user enter creds for correct admin and LsaEnumerateAccountsWithUserRight before, for get list of such accounts. Simply uac dialog not help here. If user select current "bad" admin

Comment: @RemyLebeau even if we start not elevated process under **current** user, uac simply ask yes/no dialog ( because user from admin group) and finally we got again same elevated admin. Even if we start uac where user can choose user account, user can select admin without required privilege

Comment: @RbMm Obviously, if the user selects the wrong admin account, that is their fault, nothing the code can do about that.  In any case, if `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials()` were used, what would be the next step after that? `CreateProcessWithLogonW()`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes. We also can first show custom ui for select correct account from list and then CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials for selected user only. UAC internally also use CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials too

Comment: CredUnPackAuthenticationBufferW can be used after CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials

Comment: November 18th, 2013:Going from an unelevated process to an elevated process is easy. You can run a process with elevation by passing the runas verb to Shell­Execute or Shell­Execute­Ex.https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643

Comment: @RbMm that is actually the way I'm trying to solve this issue right now. My plan is  to display the `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW()` with the 'CREDUIWIN_SECURE_PROMPT' flag and then using those credentials on `CreateProcessWithLogonW()`. I'm finding it hard to implement the first function though.

Comment: What and Why is hard implement? You not need implement CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials but simply call this api. And you problem not in elevation, but - you need change account, run as another user

Comment: Poor choice of words, I meant I'm having trouble calling the API. I'm new to Windows API and am still getting my bearings. The `pvInAuthBuffer` parameter that is used to populate the fields on the dialog is supposed to be a pointer to a 'credential BLOB' and I'm not quite sure what that is yet.

Comment: At the moment my guess is that the `CREDENTIALW` structure is used in that parameter but still trying it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/nf-wincred-creduipromptforwindowscredentialsw) and [CredUnPackAuthenticationBufferW()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/nf-wincred-credunpackauthenticationbufferw) seems to do the trick. You can find this implementation in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57945493/problem-with-windows-credential-prompt-credunpackauthenticationbuffer-error-50).

However, using `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW()` with the `CREDUIWIN_SECURE_PROMPT` flag ends up causing the password and domain to be random strings maybe because they are encrypted. Attempting to use `CredUnPackAuthenticationBufferW()` with the `CRED_PACK_PROTECTED_CREDENTIALS` flags results in the failure of the function.

As this goes out of the scope of this question I will explore this issue in a different one.

Comment: `CRED_PACK_PROTECTED_CREDENTIALS` flags results in the failure of the function - more exactly `ERROR_NOT_CAPABLE` - you need impersonate LocalSystem token, before call this api in such case. this is possible if you have admin group enable. or remove `CREDUIWIN_SECURE_PROMPT` flag - in this case `CredUnPackAuthenticationBufferW` will be ok, even with `CRED_PACK_PROTECTED_CREDENTIALS`

Comment: Thanks for the response. The secure environment is quite important to me in this case, could you elaborate on the impersonation of the LocalSystem token please? Tried to search for it but can't find much. Do I even need to use the `CRED_PACK_PROTECTED_CREDENTIALS` flag in order to unpack the credentials obtained on the secure prompt?

Comment: yes, you need use CRED_PACK_PROTECTED_CREDENTIALS flag (or by self call CredUnprotect on password) if you use CREDUIWIN_SECURE_PROMPT. you need open process with LocalSystem token and impersonate this token before call CredUnPackAuthenticationBufferW . if you have active admin group - this is possible

Comment: example of doing this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926890/how-to-decrypt-the-authentication-buffer-obtained-from-the-secure-desktop/76646806#76646806

Comment: also if you anywhay need impersonate LocalSystem token - possible more efficient solution - use return buffer from `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW` in call `LsaLogonUser` - you NOT need unpack it in this case. not need decrypt password too. then returned token - use in call `CreateProcessAsUserW` (this also more efficient api compare CreateProcessWithLogonW). for this api you need SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME which you can found in process tokens in the same way

Comment: How does LsaLogonUser return a valid token receiving encrypted credentials in a non-SYSTEM process?

Comment: Simply. Code will be executed in lsass.exe process